# restrictions using for loops in python

Tags: python

I have made code for the following question. I am getting the desired output. However I am not sure if my code has the proper restriction in my loop ranges. The restriction that is mentioned in the hint. Looking to see if I have done this correctly or should I be using <= instead. [image]

Most of all, if you want to have that restriction, you need to code it into your loop ranges.  Just use the previous loop's variable as the starting value, and you'll have the desired restriction.

```
import numpy as np

lower = 20
upper = 201
b = np.arange(lower, upper)

a = b**5

for x in b:
    for y in np.arange(x, upper):
        for z in np.arange(y, upper):
            for w in np.arange(z, upper):

                lambdas=[x,y,z,w]
                if sum(np.array(lambdas)**5) in a:

                    print((x,y,z,w))
```

Output:

```
(27, 84, 110, 133)
```

Comment: Using `np.arange(x_min, x_max)` actually creates intervals where `x_min <= x < x_max`.

Comment: okay thanks I believe I have done this correctly then

Comment: Yep, your b array will be: `array([ 20,  21,  22, ..., 198, 199, 200])`, so you're good!

Comment: thanks for your comment joe

Comment: In the case of loops I would recommend to use the built-in functions `xrange` or `range` instead of an instance of a `numpy.array` to keep performance fast. The `numpy.array` class has some overhead for an iteration. The built-in functions are about twice as fast in computing as the numpy object.

Comment: I would also suggest to put the nested loops into a function and return from that function inside the condition, if a solution is found. Then the whole linear combination of values is not calculated but all the values until the first solution.